# What inter-rater reliability test is best for continous data with multiple measures?

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics

I am doing a study with one variable with continuous data; the measurement involves measurements done by three people. I wish to do an inter-rater reliability test, e.g. with Bland-Altman analysis, but cannot find information about how it works with multiple measures. Would some other test be better?

#### Sample data

> Rater A: 380 404 381 374 377 392 373 369 371 378 392 331 366 418
>
> Rater B: 379 400 380 372 366 390 374 364 370 378 392 326 364 424
>
> Rater C: 379 402 380 372 367 392 374 361 373 378 392 332 364 420

Answer (score 4):

Usually the [intraclass-coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation) is calculated in this situation. It is sensitive both to profile as well as to elevation differences between raters. If all raters rate throughout the study, report ICC(2, k); if only one rater rates everything and the other only rate, say, 20% to check the interrater agreement, then you should report ICC(2, 1).