# inter-rater reliability for numeric variables

Tags: r, reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation, cohens-kappa

I've seen some questions on **inter-rater reliability** here for *categorical* variables. I'm wondering what would be an adequate approach to test **inter-rater reliability between two raters for a ***numeric*** variable** ?

- Suppose, for example, that I have two teachers assessing students on a test and I need to check the teachers (aka, raters) reliability. Both teachers will provide numerical scores/grades for the tests.

As far as I'm concerned, both Cohen's Kappa and Weighted kappa are for categorical and ordinal variables (respectively, right?). I've seen approaches to use **Cronbach's Alpha** or **intraclass correlation - ICC** or even **Pearson's correlation** , would any of these  be adequate or any other test?

This is more of a theorical question, but tips on calculating this in **R Studio** would be much appreciated as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question reminded me of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6430129/), which had human raters rate facial expressions using a joystick, so continuous movement equated with facial intensity. The authors used several strategies, including Krippendorf's a, Fleiss' k, ICC, and simple coefficient matching, so at the very least there is precedence for ICC on continuous data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per literature ([Analyzing Rater Agreement](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=oX95AgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) p.115-122), ICC is indeed the solution for the case where we can't relate the data as categorical. This comes alongside Cronbach's $\alpha$ (which is used for test-retest cases) and of course Spearman's correlation $\rho$.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16653/what-inter-rater-reliability-test-is-best-for-continous-data-with-multiple-measu) provides a similar answer.

Comment: thank you, @Spatzle, I've just read the chapter of the material you've recommended. Things are clearer now. Authors mention that Cronbach's α is a special case of ICC, but this is not clear to me yet, I've seen elsewhere that they'd be the same thing, I'm a bit confused. Any thoughts? Concerning correlation, as far as I'm concerned, the 'consistent' approach would equal Pearson's rho, right?

Comment: @LarissaCury There are different formulations of the ICC that answer different questions. One of these formulations, often called ICC(C,k), is equivalent to Cronbach's alpha. But the other formulations will differ.