# Should we test only 20% of the sample for intraclass correlation coefficient?

Tags: r, correlation, reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I'm currently calculating an [intraclass correlation coefficient for my data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595649/inter-rater-reliability-for-numeric-variables/595743#595743). As far as I'm concerned, the best choice (following [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4913118/) approach and the approach kindly recommended on the previous post answer) is:

**Model:** *2-way random effects*  ## two teachers' assessment of the same group of students on an exam (it could be any other pair of teachers randomly selected, thus I believe it's generalizable) 
**Type:** *average* ## we'll be using the two-teacher's average in further analysis 
**Definition:** *absolute* agreement

- code:

```
### check if variance is homogeneous:
car::leveneTest(data$RATER1 ~ data$RATER2) ##I don't know if it's necessary, but I've seen that ICC relies on the assumption that variance is homogeneous

### run it:
library(irr)
icc(data[,2:3], model = "twoway", type = "agreement", unit = "average")
```

That being said, I've seen elsewhere some comments on using only 20 to 25% of the sample to calculate ICC, such as in [this](https://europepmc.org/article/ppr/ppr503700) article and in another internet post, but not nowhere else. Why is that?

**Question:**

- **1** Is it ok to use the whole sample or Should I only perform it with 20 to 25% of the data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preamble**

In the article you cite (Tong et al. 2022), production recordings codings (i.e., the DV) were coded by either author 2 or author 3 (i.e., each production recording was initially coded by a single coder). Because the authors are interested in calculating rater agreement, such a data set is not sufficient because each production recording was only rated once by one of the two coders. Instead of simply having each coder code all production recordings (which I assume would take a considerable amount of time), the authors instead just randomly selected 25% of the production recordings to be coded by both coders.

**Answer**

> Is it ok to use the whole sample or should I only perform it with 20 to 25% of the data? Thanks in advance.

Now, to answer your question. You do **NOT** need to sample 20%, 25%, or any % of your data to calculate the ICC. You are not looking to collect additional data, as (I assume) you are just looking to calculate the ICC with the data you have.

**References**

Tong, S. X., Tsui, R. K., Law, N. S. H., Fung, L. S. C., Chiu, M. M., & Cain, K. (2022). “And this one’s juuust right!”: Prosody Predicts Reading Comprehension in Hong Kong Chinese-English Bilingual Children.

Comment: ohhh, got it! crystal clear, thank you, @Preston !! Now I understood why they've made the 25% subset.  Yeah, I had two teachers rate all students scores (both teachers rated all students), I don't think I'll be collecting extra data. I may open another post for this, but this is my first time calculating an ICC (the last time, i've calculated Cronbach alpha on a very similar situation, but I believe this approach is more suitable), should I always perform Levene's test on the data before calculating ICC?

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped! Personally, I do not perform Levene's test in the context of multilevel modeling (MLM), though this does not mean it is not a good idea. I just came across an article (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00273171.2022.2077290?journalCode=hmbr20) discussing this, and they believe Levene's test should be used more often in the context of it should be used more often. Perhaps you should ask a question about this, as CV has active users who are more knowledgeable about HLMs than I am.

Comment: Also, from both the article you posted and your other CV questions, I see you are working with language assessment data (same as me!). Given this, it may make sense to look into generalizability theory (gtheory). e.g., see https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0265532218809396?casa_token=3tysei90iJ0AAAAA%3A-YGEKjLBzXm0lXf96PNNJxUY_IvOj8pP5ij1TD9y0Pzpbyb7lpnABYU5M-s-dYxBchApLbvwyQn0XQ